# How to make text hidden on overflow in td when the table positioned between two elements

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a header with logo, table of some data and some button. Data in table can be different and large. So I want to hide the text on overflow.

Normal view:

[image]

When it overflowed:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I tried to add to td in css:
`overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;`
But it doesn't help me.

```css
.top-row {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: initial;
  word-break: break-word;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

td:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.oi {
  width: 32px;
  top: -2px;
  color: white;
}

.gradient-main-theme {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0f0e40, #16436d);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="gradient-main-theme">
  <div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">LOGO</a>
      <table class="fl-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Username: Igor</td>
          <td class="vertical-line">Email: kek@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Profilo: Some profile</td>
          <td class="vertical-line">Code: 234232</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <NavLink>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
              <span class="oi oi-menu"></span>
            </button>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-17sjf4?file=/styles.css:120-171))

Answer (score 0):

use @media only screen for example
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px)

that font size and size div change

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I don't need to change size of anything. My goal is to hide overflowed text in the table.